# Regular Expression error using Visual Basic for Applications

Tags: regex, excel, vba, basic

Testing using http://www.regexr.com/ the pattern `\"([\s\S]*?)\"` works to match my target string. However, in my code I get a type mismatch and am not sure why, the IDE changed the way the the string is formatted within the quotes

```
Dim Matches
Dim objectRegularExp As RegExp

If Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
FileName = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
Open FileName For Input As #1
yourText = Input(LOF(1), #1)
Close #1
LengthOfFile = Len(yourText)

'create regular expression

Set objectRegularExp = New RegExp
With objectRegularExp
     .Pattern = "" \ "(\s\S*?)\"""                 <type mismatch runtime error
     .Global = True
     .MultiLine = True
End With
Set Matches = objectRegularExp.Execute(yourText)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotes are wrong.

Strings are enclosed in quotes. To enclose quotes in strings you need 2 quotes. You have two quotesat beginning of your string (so an empty string)You have a single quote in the middle of your string. That terminates the string if it was validin the first place.

Normally we use the non lazy way like so

.Pattern = Chr(34) & " \ " & Chr(34) & "(\s\S*?)\" & chr(34)

Comment: This is the pattern that that worked The use of the Chr(34) never occurred to me. I will read up on the use of double quotes       .Pattern = Chr(34) & "(\s\S*?)" & Chr(34). Thanks @mfitzp